# Soft: Why does the existence of a singularity cause problems for deRham cohmology?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, analytic-geometry

I've heard that if a variety has a singularity then the deRham theory has "problems". What exactly are these?
Im guessing there is some sort of issue with the defintion of a differential form, but what exactly?

I'm guessing the deRham theorem fails to apply (but why)?

Comment: Well, one issue is that locally, around a singular, one cannot define a smooth patch. For example, any self intersecting curve has a singular point at the self intersection. Around this point, the variety looks something like a cross, So it does not locally "look" like the real line.

Comment: Yup I do know that therte is no diffeomorpihsms around p to C^n, but what does this have to do with cohomology?

Comment: Im guessing the derham theroem no longer applies but why?

Comment: Well, if there are singularities, there is no de Rham cohomology...

Comment: Why though? (thats essentially my question, why are the khlaer forms not defined?)

Comment: Because de Rham cohomology is defined  on manifolds, and manifolds are not allowed to have singularities!

Comment: (Onee can define generalizations of de Rham cohomology, using cyclic homology and other more elaborate constructions, but that is rather different —in particular, de Rham's theorem does not apply at all to these more refined theories)

Comment: Yes, but say were interested in the Derham theory of $Spec(A)$, which is singular at some point.  Why can't we compute it via the algebraic de Rham complex?  Since we may still define modules of Kahler forms, and form the ususal Kozul resolution?

Comment: Well, as I said, that theory has nothing to do with the one to which de Rham's theorem applies. It is a theorem of Grothendieck and Hartshorne that cohomology of the de Rham complex constructed from Kahler forms on an variety (what one would call the algebraic de Rham cohomology) gives the expected result in the case of smooth varieties.

Comment: In the presence of singularities, everything is more complicated.

Comment: Yup im familiar with that result for propoer schemes, but then again I'm guessing the only issue is that there "is no derham theorem" when we want to relate everything back to singular theory... (oh my algebraic background is much greater than my differential background)

Comment: There is no de Rham theorem because the statement of the algebraic de Rham theorem is simply false in the presence of singularities. Compute a few examples!

Comment: hmm... thats basically what I thought, but is there any simple examples?

Comment: Well, what have *you* tried? I suggest you pick a nice singular curve and try it out.

Comment: (Sketch) Well my idea is that say $Spec(A)$ is a singular scheme of dimension $d$ as a topological space..  Then its singular cohomology vanishes above d, however.. its Hochschild cohmological dimension is bounded below by A's global dimension which is infinite by Serre (since A cannot be regular), therefore the morphism in the HKR theorem implies (which is not an iso in this case) that the higher kahler forms do not vanish... hence the two theories cannot line up because of dimension issues
(but this proof uses machinery I have not introduced at that point of my paper)

Comment: If you really want to know exactly what breaks down, it is the face that smooth differential forms cannot be defined. In fact, a basic starting point to defining the forms is that the tangent space at every point is isomorphic. Smooth differential $k$ forms are defined to be $\Lambda^{k}(V)\otimes C^{\infty}(M;\mathbb{R})$, where $V$ is a typical fiber of the tangent bundle. However, at a singular point, the tangent space is not well defined. Neither are smooth functions.

Comment: The algebraic de Rham theorem does not say that the homology of the algebraic de Rham complex computes the singular cohomology of the Spec of the algebra in the smooth case: it computes the singular cohomology of the corresponding analytic space.

Comment: ^Ya but I meant that as a sous-entendu (I ran out of characters to give greater dets. )

Comment: Well, it was quite not sous entendu at all. The devil is in the details.

Comment: @user43687 Cool, so it was just a lack of definition of the thing, sicne there cannot be a locally trivialisable cotangent sheaf of the space, ok perfect !! :D  Thank you so much

Comment: Moreover, the Kahler forms *do* vanish above the dimension of the scheme, singular or not. The problem is that it is no true that Hochschild homology is equal to the Kahler forms in that case (a little part of the Hochschild homology is the exterior powers of the Kahler differentials: in Loday's book you'll find the so called Hodge decomposition of HH: one of the summands is Kahler forms)

Comment: Cool, thanks alot guys :)